# gnu-screen command to re-split screen after unspltting

Tags: gnu-screen, split-window

Is there a way to return to split screen after unsplitting (to focus on one window)?

When I need to focus I use Ctrl+a+Q, and this closes all except current window. BUT to return to split screen as before, I need to manually split each screen and reconnect to each session.

Is there any shortcut or binding that I can use to re-split the screen session after un-splitting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated the description